# Show Special Characters in android

Tags: android

I am working in one application in i have to show following characters

`Chanéac`

`YÃ»ka`

But when i call this webservice this characters are converted into some other characters like

`Chanéac` Converted to `Chan&eacute;ac`

`YÃ»ka`   Converted to `y&Atlide;&raquo;ka`

Please give me some solution
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UTF-8 format with whatever you are using to read from the Webservice in your android app, for example, if you are using a BufferReader:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
  new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
```

Edit:

And it seems like what you need is [HTML entity decoding](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) in android, try something like this:

```
Html.fromHtml(string);
```

Comment: I am using utf-32 format ,but when i call webservice its give me this type of characters ���������������������������������������

Comment: Did you implement the webservice? Try to unescape the characters after you receive them.

Comment: Seems like what you have to do here is HTML entity decode. Please check my updated answer.